# ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET foo = NOT EXCLUDED.foo not working as expected

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[image]

Why is the column "active" not toggling its boolean state as the picture shows?
Table users_strategies got primary key contraint pkey(id_strategy,id_account)

Comment: Please include terminal output as preformatted text and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing `true` as the "excluded" value, `not true` will be false, so the column will be set to false.

If you want to **toggle** the value, you need to negate the existing value:

```
set active = not user_strategies.active
```

---

For future posts, please show code as formatted text, not (hardly readable) screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

You are negating your *conflicting* input argument, which you set as `true`, but you expected `not true` to yield `true`?

Just skip the negation you you'll update the row with exactly the value you specified with the insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO users_strategies (id_strategy, id_account, active)
VALUES (1, 48, true)
ON CONFLICT (id_strategy, id_account) DO
    UPDATE SET active = excluded.active
    RETURNING active, risk
;
```